# Overriding key strings of an @autowired/@Inject Map<String,Object>?

Tags: java, spring, dictionary, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control

I have several Spring beans of type CustomerApiLink, say the name of those beans are 'ableCustomer', 'bravoCustomer' and 'charlieCustomer' respectively (this is just an example). Now I inject all of them into a Map through

```
//DI through annotation
@Inject
private Map<String,CustomerApiLink> apis;
```

But I found that by default Spring IoC container always use their name as map key, I want to override this, to get a Map of:

able-> bean ref="ableCustomer";

bravo-> bean ref="bravoCustomer";

charlie-> bean ref="charlieCustomer";

Is it possible to do this with annotation? Or I have to create another util bean in an xml file?

Answer (score 3):

I have done this multiple times.  I usually `@Inject` a `Set` of the object I want to the constructor or a setter, and create a `Map` at that point.

```
public class MyObject {
    private Map<String, CustomerApiLink> apiLinks;

    @Inject
    public MyObject(Set<CustomerApiLink> apis) {
        apiLinks = new HashMap<String, CustomerApiLink>();
        for(CustomerApiLink api : apis) {
            apiLinks.put(api.getName(), api);
        }
    }
}
```

Of course, with this solution, it requires a way to get the key from the `CustomerApiLink` object.  In this case, I assumed a method called `getName()` would be present.

Answer (score 0):

No XML needed, but you can annotate a setter method instead of a field and process the supplied map yourself in the method.

```
@Inject
public void setApis(Map<String,CustomerApiLink> apis){
    this.apis = new HashMap<String,CustomerApiLink>();
    // now copy values from the incoming map to your internal map
    // using keys of your own choice
}
private Map<String,CustomerApiLink> apis;
```